# Reloading google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, iframe, refresh

i have 3 different google maps on my site, one for when viewing on desktop, tablet and mobile, when i resize my browser which people might do the new map pointer that has now resized isn't in the right place until i refresh the page, i want to just reload the iframe, im very new to javascript and tried this but its nots working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            if( $(window).width() == 985){

                document.getElementById('map-desk').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
            }

            if( $(window).width() == 975){

                document.getElementById('map-tab').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
            }

            if( $(window).width() == 765){

                document.getElementById('map-mob').contentWindow.location.reload(true);
            }

        </script>
```

so like when the screen equals a certain width the iframe with that id reloads or refreshes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no actual event handler so it'll only fire once, when the browser loads (which is obviously not what you want). As you're using jQuery, wrap your code in:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    // code goes here...

});
```

... which will run the code inside every single time there's even a minute change to the browser size. Though you're going to come across the issue that `$(window).width()` is very rarely going to hit that *exact* pixel value. I'm not certain of the best solution, but something involving checking the condition +/- 30 pixels either way or so might work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the following event in jQuery

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
  //your code to resize and reload here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Google maps reloads itself if the mapdiv is resized. Give 100% width to mapdiv. It will fit the size of the window. If you want to change the contents of maps (layers, markers, routes...), you should use google map events. Events, options and methods are listed here:https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference